ExpressRoute (Microsoft peering) connectivity to Azure Virtual Desktop
We are working on a requirement to help our customer end users based out in Philippines connect via ExpressRoute (Microsoft peering) to Azure Cloud AVD solution hosted in Azure SG and JP region.
Hence, we wanted to check if Azure AVD solution is supported via ExpressRoute Microsoft Peering connectivity model.
The Philippines delivery center will be connected via ExpressRoute circuit to ExpressRoute Gateway hosted in Azure Cloud Singapore / Japan Subscription managed by CSP partner, which has to connect back to Azure AVD solution hosted in Azure Cloud Singapore / Japan Subscription managed by third-party vendor.
Let me know, if above Azure AVD is supported via ExpressRoute - Microsoft Peering network connectivity path.enter image description here
